# What are the limiting factors of Kepler, comparing to Fermi?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

It is not a strictly programming question, but knowing hardware is the critical part of programming.

So I start this thread, hope people here can share their experience in  programming on Kepler (GK10X or GK110).

First I start mine:

I am doing some programming on GK110 at the moment, for some applications, GK110 is significantly faster than a Fermi, close to its theoretical peak (e.g. 2.5-3X faster). But for others, it isn't, (e.g. only ~ 50%-60% faster).

Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me, the main performance bottleneck of Kepler is resource pressure is very high here:

On a per-SM level, Fermi actually have far more resources comparing to GK110, on each SM, Fermi only has one SIMT unit, whilst Kepler has 6.

Yet on each SM,  Fermi has 32K registers file, a maximum of 1536 active threads, whilst on each SM of Kepler, there are only 33% more active threads, 100% more registers, with 800% insturction-issue units, and same amount of L1 cache.

The latencies regarding memory and computation are about the same in absolute terms (half in terms of GPU cycles).

So resource-pressure is much higher on GK110, comparing to GF110.

With 800% of instruction-issue units, it seems that Nvidia want to use more aggressive TLP and ILP to hide latency on Kepler, but it is certainly not as flexible, since L1 cache is the same, and active threads is only increased by 33% instead of 500% like its SIMT units.

So, to utilize maximum efficiency of Kepler, it is much harder,  first code has to contain significantly more ILP yet take significantly less shared-memory to take the advantage of a massive instruction-issue unit of Kepler, secondly, on a per-warp level, workflow has to be very computationally intensive such that Kepler schedule don't need to switch a lot of warps to hide latency (and it certainly don't have a lot of available warps to chose from to begin with).

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: Sure, since I want to hear more about practical problems on programming on Kepler.

Comment: SO isn't really intended to serve as a vehicle for open-ended discussion threads.  The types of questions best answered here are specific questions related to a specific programming issue.  It's very difficult to address a wide-ranging topic such as yours in a single Question/Answer SO format.  SO questions are not intended to be general discussion threads.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the Kepler (GK110) [whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf), perhaps compare to the Fermi [whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf) and then study the Kepler [tuning guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/index.html).  The tuning guide will answer many of your questions about the differences  going to Kepler and how to get the most out of Kepler.